# Ionic App - SQLite error "plugin_not_installed" only when running app in iOs devices

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I builded an hybrid app using Ionic3+AngularJS and it uses the SQLite database.

When I run the app in Android's devices it works perfectly but when I try to run it in an iPhone or iPad I get the following error: **plugin_not_installed**. It happens when the app tries to create the database.

This is how it's creating the database:

```
  public getDB(){
    return this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'namedatabase.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).catch( error => this.showError(error));
  }
```

The catch() is called and it shows the error message "plugin_not_installed".

SQLite installed using:

```
 $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
 $ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same issue when I run my app in an android emulator using

> ionic cordova run android -lc

When the app start, everything is ok. But after a couple of changes in my code and a save command, the app reload and show in my console

> console.warn: Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins / and reinstalling them. 
>   console.warn: 'Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but it's not installed. 
>   console.warn: Install the SQLite plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage' 
>   console.log: err "plugin_not_installed"

Even if I followed what the console asked me to do, I'm still getting the same error and it cannot create my SQLite database

What I did next is to re-run the app using the run command above, but it waste a lot of time for me to wait for the app to get started again... and again :(

```
createDBFile() {
    this.sqlite.create({
        name: DB_NAME,
        location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.db = db;
        console.log('BDD cree')
        this.stockageLocal.get('dbstatus').then(opened => {
            if (opened) {
                console.log('DB deja ouvert');
            }
            else {
                console.log('create all table')
                this.createTables();
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(' err', JSON.stringify(err))
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: plugin_not_installed.
I resolved putting console.log check after the promise errors and seeing that the table didn't exist.

The code:

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'ionicdb.db',
  location: 'default'
})
.then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql('create table if not exists MY_SQLITE_STORAGE(key VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR(32))', [])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Executed Create table if not exists');
      this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'Table created ',
        duration: 5000,
        position: 'center'
      }).present();
    }).catch(e => console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(e)));
}).catch(e => console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(e)));
```